# My list remains empty

Tags: python

This is my program, at the moment I am trying to figure out how to write a function as a list.
Every time I execute this code, the function list remains empty. I am new to python and a little troubleshooting from fresh eyes would really help me out right now!

```
command = raw_input()
function = []

while command != "done":
    command = raw_input()

if command == "help":
    print "num"
    print "var"
    print "power"
    print "done"

elif command == "num":
    num = raw_input()
    num = int(num)
    function.append(num)
    print function

elif command == "power":
    power = raw_input()
    power = int(power)
    function.append("^", power)
    print function

elif command == "var":
    function.append("x")
    print function

elif command == "done":
    for i in function:
        print function[i]
```

Comment: is this `function.append("^", power)` possible?

Comment: You keep reading the commands until you see "done". Your code never executes any command other than "done".

Comment: "My list remains empty" was the saddest of the Python ballads.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few issues here:

- You are immediately throwing your code into the `while` loop, which will be iterated over until you input `"done"`, in which case none of your `if` statements evaluate to `true`. You want to place all of your conditional statements in your `while` loop, so you are checking the conditions with each iteration.
- Additionally, you can remove the `elif` for `"done"` as once you exit the `while` loop you know your user input must be `"done"`,
- `append` takes only 1 argument, so `function.append("^", power)` will fail.

Comment: Donkey Kong, agreed. You've got to indent the following `if/elif/elif/else` statements accordingly so that they are included in the while loop. Then make sure that each iteration of the `if/elif`'s is checking/asking for the current value or prompting for new value of command. If true, do this. Else check `command` so on and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

Strip new line from command

`command = raw_input()`

to

`command = raw_input().strip()`

Answer (score 0):

Your entire if/elif block needs to be indented so that it becomes a part of your while loop.

also, in your final block :

```
elif command == "done":
    for i in function:
        print function[i]
```

the iterator returns the value itself, not the index.  so, that becomes:

```
elif command == "done":
    for i in function:
        print i
```

or, even more simply:

```
print function
```